# Enhancing copy marco to specify a given number of characters from a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in Excel that accurately copies all the data from one page to another.

```
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Data").Range("A1:L" & bottomL)
        If (c.Value = "Title1" Or c.Value = "Title2" Or c.Value = "Title3" Or c.Value = "Title4") Then
            Intersect(c.Parent.Columns("A:Q"), c.EntireRow).Copy Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("A" & x + 1)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next c
```

Now, I need to add a line that specifies how many characters to copy from a given column (i.e. only copy the first 9 characters from column C), similar to the code below:

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("C:C").Cells
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, 9)
Next cell
```

What is the easiest way I might be able to insert this seamlessly into my original code?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried `LEFT` function?

Comment: Not yet, since I'm not sure how to insert it in my existing code without disturbing the rest of the copying algorithm

Comment: Is there a way I can insert a code of line to truncate the copied cell as it is being copied from one sheet to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your first loop :

```
For Each c In sheets("Portfolio").Range("A1:A" & X-1)
    c.offset(0,1)=left(c.offset(0,1),9) 'For column "B" in sheets "Portfolio"
    c.offset(0,5)=left(c.offset(0,5),9) 'For column "F" in sheets "Portfolio"
    '...
Next c
```

Comment: Works perfectly, albeit with a decent crunch on resources.  Thanks so much!